# Upgrade from Sql server 2008 to Sql Server 2008 R2 didn't update running version

Tags: sql-server-2008, upgrade

I/m trying to replicate a database whose .bak was created using SQL server 2008 R2, as in my local machine I was running SQL server 2008 I'm trying to upgrade.

It does the upgrade and the management studio shows the actual R2 version but the running instance is not changing, i.e. the Sql Server in the connection stills stays 10.0.1600

I uninstall everyting and run first 2008 and then the update, so I'm pretty sure it is the default instance and not a named one. And I couldn't install directly 2008 R2 because I was running through all kind of problems and that's why I'm trying to install 2008 first and then update

Anyone know if I can change that MSSQLSERVER version to the proper one?

Thanks

Update
When running select@@version as per Giorgi's comment I get this

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64)   Jul  9 2008 14:17:44   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )
```

Comment: May be you upgraded only client tools without engine?

Comment: I don't think so, but to double check it tried to run the update again and it can't find anything to update

Comment: Standard question: did you restart the machine?

Comment: Can you run this?  `SELECT @@VERSION`